# Are opinion questions allowed?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Questions where there isn't a clear-cut answer, but a range of opinions.  For example, questions about whether one *should* do something, rather than whether one *can* do something according to halacha.

Comment: "should" questions can be phrased as "what have rabbinic authorities suggested in such circumstances?" or "have similar cases been discussed in responsa?" to make them less opinion-y.

Comment: I try to ask these as "what are the issues with X", which invites people to bring arguments for any interpretation while still expecting support rather than just opinion.

Answer (score 3):

[The FAQ list](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask) says, in part:

> To prevent your question from being flagged [and possibly removed](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion), **avoid** asking subjective questions where …
>
> - every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”

And, indeed, a standard closure reason for questions is:

> As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion. If you feel that this question can be improved and possibly reopened, [see the FAQ](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/faq#close) for guidance.

As it says, though, this applies only to subjective questions. If I find a question worded as "what should one do", I'd normally assume it means to ask the objective question "what does God want one to do, as far as we know via authoritative interpreters of His will" (though it should certainly be reworded to make that clear).